# How to create a diagonal gradient background on CSS?

Tags: html, css, gradient

How to create a diagonal gradient background but still keep the box content in position?

[The diagonal background more or less like this and the box content still in position as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7YCq.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: thanks for the advice @Sfili_81 i will read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `linear-gradient` value for `background`

- first parameter is the degree of the gradient
- then you have to place
  one color with percentage of space take in gradient color

to perform what you expect i can advice you 3 point

```css
.middle-gradient div {
  padding: 50px;
  border: solid 1px;
  flex: 0 0 10%
}

.middle-gradient {
  background: blue;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5%;
  width 100%;

  background: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 28%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 28% 66%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 66%);
}
```

```html
<div class="middle-gradient">
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

one good website to manipulate gradient and have exaclty the expected one is https://cssgradient.io/